# Why are spatial frequency number written as k=[0:N/2-1 -N/2:-1]'*2*pi/L

Tags: matlab, fft

In the following sample code is written     `k=[0:N/2-1 -N/2:-1]'*2*pi/L;` which are the spatial frequency numbers from the spatial Fourier transform. Why does Matlab require the `k`s to be written with the positive k's first and then the negative ones?

```
% p4.m: the 4th-order integrating-factor method for solving the% NLS equation:  
% iu_t+u_{xx}+2|u|ˆ2u=0.
L=4*pi; N=128; dt=0.01; 
tmax=2; nmax=round(tmax/dt);
dx=L/N; x=[-L/2:dx:L/2-dx]';

k=[0:N/2-1 -N/2:-1]'*2*pi/L;
E=exp(1i*k.^2*dt/2); 
E2 = E.*E;u=sin(x).^2;

udata=u; tdata=0;
for nn = 1:nmax     
    % integration begins
    v=fft(u); 
    dv1=2*1i*fft(u.*u.*conj(u));
    w=ifft((v+dv1*dt/2)./E ); 
    dv2=2*1i*E.* fft(w.*w.*conj(w));
    w=ifft((v+dv2*dt/2)./E ); 
    dv3=2*1i*E.* fft(w.*w.*conj(w));w=ifft((v+dv3*dt  )./E2); 
    dv4=2*1i*E2.*fft(w.*w.*conj(w));v=v+(dv1+2*dv2+2*dv3+dv4)*dt/6; 
    u=ifft(v./E2);
    
    if mod(nn,round(nmax/25)) == 0

        udata=[udata u]; tdata=[tdata nn*dt];end
end                                   % integration ends
waterfall(x, tdata, abs(udata')); % solution plotting
% colormap([0 0 0]); 
view(5, 60)
xlabel('x', 'fontsize', 15),
ylabel('t', 'fontsize', 15),
zlabel('|u|', 'fontsize', 15),
axis([-L/2 L/2 0 tmax 0 2]); 
    grid off
```

Comment: They aren't. It's `k=0:N-1`. But `k` is periodic, so `k=N-1` is the same as `k=-1`, and some people prefer to interpret it that way. See here for the definition of the DFT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition